# How to redirect to the particular template based on video streaming on real time using Flask and Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, flask, video-streaming

Using Flask,
I'm streaming a video capturing from my default webcam of laptop on webpage that recognize the objects.
For example,

If I will show the apple on the cam, It will automatically redirect me to apple.html

OR

If I will show the mango on the cam, It will automatically redirect me to mango.html

I want to know is it possible if we can do that ?

Here my Flask.py file.

```
@app.route('/apple')
def apple():
    return render_template('apple.html')

def gen(camera1):
    while True:
        label, frame = camera1.get_frame()
        if label=="apple":
            print("Inside If condition")
            return redirect('/apple')        
        else:
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')


@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(VideoCamera()),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')``

#But its not working!! Am I missed something ?
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is, you could every time you get a frame from the webcam check if its a mango or apple (by feeding it through a trained CNN). Then if its one or the other you use a flag to show the template apple.html or mango.html. Or better yet you use the same template fruit.html but you use jinja to show different things in the template depending on the mango/apple flag you setup previously.

Comment: Thanks For commenting, I have updated my answer please let me know If I missed something.!

Comment: Is this function really labeling your frame? `camera1.get_frame()`

Comment: Yes it's really labelling my frame. If I do print(label) inside if function then it will give me label named apple but the problem is just with the auto redirection. I don't know if I missed something.

Comment: Do you always get apple or you get mango too when you show a mango?

Comment: Yes. I get apple printed when I show apple and get mango printed when I show mango. But it just stucked on redirecting automatically to a new HTML page.

Comment: Well then add an `elif label == 'mango': return redirect('/mango')`?

Comment: elif label == 'mango': return redirect('/mango') is not working.